# CSS Navigation Drops only in Google Chrome. Rails Tutorial Feedback

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I am going through the awesome Rails Tutorial http://railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec:custom_css I've run into an issue with the Navigation dropping down into the body of the page, but this only happens in Chrome (I'm on Linux, Ubuntu 10.10 if that matters). Here is a screenshot and a URL to show you actually what the navigation looks like before and after as I really can't explain it as well as I'd like. If I refresh a couple of times in Chrome it drops down the page like the "after" image I uploaded.

Here is a URL to the web page so you can recreate it: 
http://afternoon-wind-61.heroku.com/pages/home

Try it in Chrome, Firefox and IE as well.

Any insight in why this is happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

in /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb solved this issue for me.